# FS Won't save to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UghIU.png)

My code won't save to the file (I'm just making an IP logger as a test)
I want it to add a new line in a JSON file for every IP it gets

Comment: do the file exists? do your user (or node's user) have read/write permission to the file? why is the file on ```/ip/ip.json``` rather than ```/var/...``` or ```/home/user/...```?

Comment: You need to add the errors if any in the console. Also, try pasting the code directly instead attaching as an Image.

Answer (score 0):

I think your json.stringfy is not correct, it should be "JSON.stringify".